# ASM - TLINK no symbol table

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to link an .obj file to make a .com program.
I first use:
 `tasm /zi program.asm`
and then:
 `tlink /t program.obj`
but when I try to debug the .com file it runs without symbol table.

What can be wrong?
Thanks, Juanjo.

Comment: I don't think symbol tables are supported for COM files.  Have you tried building an EXE?

Comment: Hi, I did and it had symbol table

Comment: Let me turn my comment into an answer so future readers know that your question has been resolved.

Comment: @fuz thank you so much, I did not know .COM files don't have symbol table. And also thanks for your quick response!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM files do not support symbol tables as they do not keep any metadata at all.  To get a symbol table, you need to compile your code into an EXE file.  All types of EXE files (MZ, PE, NE, LE, and probably the more esoteric ones, too) support symbol tables.